# Microsoft Sync - Apply Changes Not getting Called

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have an existing application where Sync Framework is used. It was all working before and with latest changes on adding some additional columns to one of the sync tables, the sync is no more working. Wanted to know how to debug the issue as the problem I see is that the GetChanges method of WCF is getting called while the ApplyChnages isn't getting called.

Am using Sync over WCF with a Winforms application.

Comment: why dont you enable Sync Fx tracing or have a look at ApplyChangesFailed event?

Comment: ApplyChangesFailed event isnt called.

Comment: you should enable sync fx tracing in verbose mode to get more details.